# Creating custom login portal

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

Our company has several clients for some major corporations, and we're looking into giving our portal page a little something extra by having customized urls all link to the same portal.

```
client1.ourcompany.net
client2.ourcompany.net
```

Ideally, we'd like for the urls to be superficial, I found the Request.Url.ToString() function that could be utilized on the code behind, but would I still need to create custom ASPX pages for each portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you could handle this in IIS.  Basically, you set up your IIS endpoint to respond to all *.ourcompany.net requests with the same IIS application and your code can disambiguate details from there in the fashion you describe.

Answer (score 1):

Also worth adding that IIS doesn't support Wildcard subdomains for websites which share an IP (source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1872857.aspx?Automatic+subdomain+with+c+in+IIS).

As you're working for a company - this may not be a problem but worth noting just in case.

Also some information here: https://serverfault.com/questions/84921/how-to-configure-iis-wildcards-for-account-subdomains-like-basecamp <- link explains how you'd set this up in IIS by making the website respond to all requests for the IP.